# How do I create a Regular Expression to find valid URL's in a webpage?

Tags: java, regex, validation, caching

I'm writing a program that caches every webpage it can find.  It works by caching a website into a file, and then looks for all of the valid URLs in that file.  Then, it scans all of the valid URLs recursively.  The problem is, I can't find a Regex or way to find the valid URLs.  So far, this is my code:

```
public static void findAllPages(String baseURL) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(baseURL);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String cnt = ""; //HTML content read from URL
    String ln;  //Line

    while((ln = bf.readLine()) != null) {  //Read content
        cnt += (ln + "\n");
    }

    int count = 0;

    ArrayList<String> val = findUrlsInString(baseURL)

    count = val.size();

    for(int i = 0;i < count;i++) {  //Find content of links on page
        try {
            findAllPages(val.get(i));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            //Invalid URL
        }
    }
}

public static void findUrlsInString(String url) {
    //Need to filter out URLs here and put them in an ArrayList
}
```

Note: There is no reading/writing files in the code above

Comment: Changed the title to reflect the real problem: not knowing how to find valid URL's.

Comment: I won't up vote this question because, frankly, it doesn't show much research effort. Google on 'regex valid url' and you'll end up with dozens examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some `html` parser instead of regexp. One example of such parser is [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)